# How can we intercept remote push notification and change its content before it gets displayed in the notification center?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to change the content of the notification before the notification gets displayed in the notification drawer. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There's no way to do it was far as I know. What's your use case?

Comment: I guess you could use silent notifications, and decide what to show locally.

Answer (score 2):

isn't that what [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) does?

Right in the description it says

> `UNNotificationServiceExtension` object provides the entry point for a notification service app extension. This object lets you customize the content of a remote notification before the system delivers it to the user.

Comment: Are there any cons if we use Silent push notification and then create a new in-app notification?